# ignore renderbody in razor _layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a page for what u need to be signed in to watch it. So I want to try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Meine ASP.NET MVC-Anwendung</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) {
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/signin")
    }
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
        <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="../">Home</a>
                </div>
                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Link 4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Link 5</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    } else {
        @RenderBody()
    }
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Meine ASP.NET MVC-Anwendung</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I start this I get this exception

```
The RenderBody-Method wasn't called for the layoutpage "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"
```

How can I make razor ignore the RenderBody-method?

Comment: You can't. What you're doing also doesn't make sense. You should display something to an unauthenticated user also..

Comment: Yes, the unauthenticated user gets a Login form as seen in my code ;)

Comment: Still the other Simon is right, what you are trying to do doesn't make sense: it's the layout page, it's called from a content page to display stuff inside the layout (the goal being *drum roll* to have a consistent layout) you need to render the body at one point or an other. What is it you are trying to do here ?

Comment: I want to avoid that people see even the navigation before they are logged in.

Comment: Makes sense, then why don't you tell razor where to render the rest of the page ?

Comment: Because there is no rest. When I got the HomeController Index page for example, the content shouldn't be rendered. Just the login view should get rendered. I was looking for redirecting on action if the user is not authenticated, but this doesn't work like I asume...

Comment: @Knerd You set that up in the web.config in the `authentication` element. There are plenty of examples of that... everywhere.

Comment: Yeah, I found it, I am an idiot. And then I can also use the version above just add `@RenderBody()` in the else block.

Comment: @Knerd you are missing the point of the layout page, it's suppose to be a layout where the rest of the body get rendered, there must always be something to render, just set your homepage to an anonymous access and take example from [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647804/including-the-login-form-within-the-master-layout-page-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: I changed the code a little, this is the solution I took.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note that you actually can "ignore" the content if you really want to. Normally you write `@RenderBody()` in your view code, which evaluates the body content, sticks it in a `HelperResult`, and then writes that to the output stream. In doing so, MVC marks the body as having been rendered. You can trick it into thinking the body has been rendered without actually writing anything by writing `@{ RenderBody(); }` (notice the braces) or just `RenderBody();` if already in a code context. This evaluates the body content without actually writing it to the output stream.

Comment: I actually do not need it anymore, but I gonna accept your answer, cause it gives an actual solution :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I wanted to show the body from a view and I could easily store it in a variable and show it somewhere else.

Comment: In asp.net core you can call IgnoreBody() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-7.0